# RxJs Observable to manage Skeletons

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

i have a list with data loaded by a rest call, and a skeleton shown during the rest call:

```
<div *ngIf="!loading; else skeleton">
    <span *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</span>
</div>
<ng-template #skeleton>
   <my-skeleton></my-skeleton>
</ng-template>
```

The goal is: show this skeleton only after a given timeout, because if the REST call is very fast, there will be an horrible effect, like a flash of the skeleton. The idea is: "Ok if the call take more than 500ms, set **loading** to true".

Is there any elegant solution to do this with observables? Or i am completely on the wrong way?

(I am on an Angular 9 application)

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a combination of `concat`, `merge`, `mapTo` and `timer` you get what you want I guess:

```
readonly restCall$ = this.http.get().pipe(
  shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
);

readonly loading$ = concat(
  race(
    this.restCall$.pipe(
      mapTo(false)
    ),
    timer(500).pipe(
      mapTo(true)
    )
  ),
  this.restCall.pipe(
    mapTo(false)
  )
);
```

You change your template to:

```
<div *ngIf="!(loading$ | async); else skeleton">
    <span *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</span>
</div>
<ng-template #skeleton>
   <my-skeleton></my-skeleton>
</ng-template>
```

disclaimer: there might be a much more elegant solution, but I'm not seeing it right now. I'm blaming it on being late in the day, and already in the easter mood

Comment: Thanks, i reached the solution following this approach :)